# Unable to show a form as a mdiChild form using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, desktop-application

I'm building a C#(VS 2015) Desktop application. Now this application has several forms of which 'frmMain' has IsMdiContainer= true and the rest are all child forms. Now, in one of the child form 'frmChild1', has the following code under button click event.

```
if(chkMarksEntrdOrNot(tsDDBSession.ToString(), tsDDBClass.ToString()) == false)
{

}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Marks of all the applicants for the chosen Session and Class have not been entered yet. Please enter marks then come again to this menu.",Application.ProductName,MessageBoxButtons.OK);
   this.Close();
   Admission.frmAdmissionTestMarksEntryBrows fATMEB = new frmAdmissionTestMarksEntryBrows();
   //frmMain fMn = new frmMain();
   //fATMEB.MdiParent = fMn;
   fATMEB.Show();
}
```

As you can see from the above code, in the else part, i'm closing the current form and then trying to show another child form(frmAdmissionTestMarksEntryBrows). The form is showing but not as a mdiChild form. I want to show it as a mdiChild form. I hope you understand my problem.Please help.

Comment: Ask yourself.. how does this form know that it is supposed to be a MDI child form of frmMain?

Comment: Why is this commented out: `//fATMEB.MdiParent = fMn;` ? What happens if it is uncommented?

Comment: Oh.. You need an actual reference to the main form, and not try to create a new instance. Do you have this reference? For instance, if you are trying to add this new form as an mdiChild to your own parent, try : `fATMEB.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;` (before closing yourself)

Comment: Thanks @Oguz Ozgul, your solution works perfectly for me

Comment: Adding as a sloution then. Please accept. Be safe.

Comment: During these days also its better to stay home, stay safe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//frmMain fMn = new frmMain();
//fATMEB.MdiParent = fMn;
```

You are not setting the MdiParent of the form before showing it.

You need an actual reference to the main form `frmMain` (because from the comments above, we understand that frmMain is the desired parent), and should not try to create a new instance.

If you are trying to add this new form as a mdichild to your own parent, try :

```
fATMEB.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
```

(before closing yourself)